# How to determine if a cell in PivotTable.DataBodyRange is a "total"

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I create a pivot table in code (C#) with grand totals for columns. How can I determine, if a cell in the `PivotTable.DataBodyRange` is a total? I loop through the cells like so:

`foreach (Excel.Range cell in pvtTable.DataBodyRange) {
        //I need to determine if "cell" is a total or not.
    }`

See image. The cells that are totals are highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Asger!  A small modification is needed. VS says pvtTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(pl.Position).Cells is incorrect syntax - Non-invocable method 'Range.Rows' cannot be used as a method. Also pl.Position is the position within the PivotRowAxis, which may not be the actual row # in the Excel worksheet. Nonetheless. your answer provided a solution...THANKS!

Comment: Thanks, I clarified my answer concerning `PivotLine.Position`, which represents the row number of the `DataBodyRange` (and is never equal to the Excel row number).

Comment: Concerning the error: Would `pvtTable.DataBodyRange.Rows[pl.Position].Cells` be working?

Comment: Yes, the two changes pl.Position and [...] makes your answer 100% PERFECT! Thanks again...you are the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

- Loop over the rows by looping over `PivotTable.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines`
- Each `PivotLine.Position` is equivalent the row number *within* the `PivotTable.DataBodyRange` (not the Excel row number), starting with 1
- If `PivotLine.LineType = xlPivotLineSubtotal`, then you are in a desired row

The result might be something like this:

```
foreach (Excel.PivotLine pl in pvtTable.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines)
{
    if (pl.LineType == Excel.XlPivotLineType.xlPivotLineSubtotal)
    {
        foreach (Excel.Range cell in pvtTable.DataBodyRange.Rows[pl.Position].Cells){
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cell);
        }
    }
}
```